# CSS: Background color issues

Tags: css, background-color

Added background color in body selector and does not respond. I want to change the background color in css not html, how is this possible. Here is the HTML and CSS

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>
    <title>positors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grid.css"/>
</header>
<body>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="photo.png"><sub>PositorS</sub></li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to reference the stylesheet.

Comment: can you provide your full html page code?

Comment: CSS caching issue? Does it help to clear the browser cache? Or else, when in doubt, try another browser.

Comment: Could be a path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure is incorrect. Instead of the `header` tag you should use the `head` tag.

Correct structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

One way to debug your problem is to open DevTools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox) and select the element you expect to be styled or to check the console if you have some path related issues and the `HTML` page cannot find the `CSS` file you have linked.

Like this:
[image]